# Qt5.12.0 relative path doesn't work but absolute path works

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt5.12.0 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.
I can load files using absolute path, but can't do that using relative path. However, I want to use the relative path to robust the code. I think the absolute path is not maintainable as relative path.

I have tried `QDir::currentPath();`, `QApplication::applicationDirPath()`, and `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();` but they all give me the absolute path.
[image]

Below are `loadPhotos`, so far, only the `print dir.entryList(QDir::Files)` part is used.

```
// load photo cantainer
void TimerDialog::loadPhotos(const QString &path)
{
    qDebug() << "in func loadPhotos, path is: " << path;
//    in func loadPhotos, path is:  "./images"
//    QDir dir("");
    QDir dir(path);
    // trevase current directory
    QStringList fileList = dir.entryList(QDir::Files);
    qDebug() << "in func loadPhotos, fileList is: " << fileList;
//  TODO in func loadPhotos, fileList is:  ()

    for (int i=0; i<fileList.size();i++) {
        QImage image(path+"/"+fileList.at(i));
        qDebug() << "fileList.at(i): " << fileList.at(i);
        m_vecPhotos << image;
    }
    QStringList folderList = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs|
                                           QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    for (int i = 0; i < folderList.size(); ++i) {
        loadPhotos(path+"/"+folderList.at(i));
    }
}
```

I put `images` folder under the project file, which is `bili_tedu_timer`. There are 20 pictures in the images folder.
[image]

I have disabled `Shadow build` in `Projects mode`
[image]

I tried `qmake` in Qt creator, but it still doesn't work @ניר

[image]

Comment: You use qmake or CMake?

Comment: You have not shared loadPhotos(), so hard to say what it does.

Comment: @ניר   I use qmake

Comment: @LászlóPapp I've re-edit the question, please have a check

Answer (score 0):

**It is truth that if the absolute path works, the relative path will work.** The question is, where is the current directory?

I've implemented three kinds of ways to see where the current directory is. But I am unaware that the current directory is `MacOS`, which is not project directory `bili_tedu_timer`, where I put `images` folder.
[image]

From the current Path output,`bili_tedu_timer` is THREE level upper than `MacOS`, so use `../../../` to get to the correct folder.

Actually, it's quite straightforward. But as a beginner as me, I don't have the sensitive about the program. What I did was I `save a file` (Thx to my roommate, she told me this method) to find out where I am, [reference](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-save-a-file-qt-widget-C++.php). Without surprise, I am in `MacOS`. I suddenly realized that I was so close to the solution.

[image]